# Replace the value of the variable by the value of the same variable but from different row

Tags: mysql, variables

i need a help, i have a table in mysql with variable flight_id which looks like:

```
flight_id
1R10005
1M10000000000
1M10000000001
1M10000000002
1M10000000003
1M10000000004
1M10000000005
1M10000000006
1M10000000007
1R10006
1M10000000008
1M10000000009
1M10000000010
1M10000000011
1R10007
1M10000000012
1M10000000013
1M10000000014
etc....
```

i want to replace all `flight_id` which starts with '1M100' by the flight_id '1R1'
i want to obtain table like this:

```
1R10005
1R10005
1R10005
1R10005
1R10005
1R10005
1R10005
1R10005
1R10005
1R10006
1R10006
1R10006
1R10006
1R10006
1R10007
1R10007
1R10007
1R10007
```

can someone help me with mysql query please :)

Comment: you have to replace all flight_id that starts with 1M100 with the last flight id that starts with 1R1? or you just have to replace the string 1M100 with 1R1?

Comment: yes, i've to replace them with last flight_id which starts with 1R1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ID, or some other column to order your table. If you have an ID, you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE
  flights inner join (
    select f1.id, max(f2.id) as new_id
    from flights f1 left join flights f2
         on f1.flight_id like '1M100%'
            and f2.flight_id like '1R1%'
            and f1.id>f2.id
    group by f1.id) fmax
  on flights.id=fmax.id
  inner join flights fdesc
  on fmax.new_id=fdesc.id
SET
  flights.flight_id = fdesc.flight_id
```

Inner subquery returns, for every flight id, the `new_id` which is the `id` where to get the description from. This `new_id` is the maximum id < than current row, with the description like 1R1.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myTable set flight_id=REPLACE(`flightId`, '1M100', '1R1') 
WHERE `flightId` LIKE '1M100%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select CASE 
   WHEN `fklightId` like '1M100%' THEN REPLACE(`flightID`, '1M100', '1R1') END 
from your_tablename as flightId;
```

So now `1M10000000001` will be output as `1R100000001`

And if you want to remove more zeros then increase number of zeros in the replace string

```
select CASE 
   WHEN `fklightId` like '1M100%' THEN REPLACE(`flightID`, '1M100000000', '1R1') END 
from your_tablename as flightId;
```

Will give `1M10000000001`  as `1R101`